# How to find the exact phrase in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have field `"name":"The leonardo da vinci"` .In mapping this field is analysed by standard analyser. When i am using `match_phrase` on this field it is also matching documents like `The leonardo da vinci US`,`The leonardo da vinci UK`,`The leonardo da vinci GBR` etc.

How can i able to get the documents that have only  `"name":"The leonardo da vinci"` without changing my mapping ?

Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an exact match, you don't need to use match phrase, just use a term query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name":"The leonardo da vinci" 
    }
  }
}
```

Check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) out for more info on term vs full text searches.

Edit: in case of an analyzed field you can add a subfield to it:

```
'name': {
  'type': 'text',
  'fields': {
    'raw': {
      'type': 'keyword'
    }
  }
}
```

reindex by populating both `name` and `name.raw` and then you can use a match query with full text search on the `name` field and a term query for exact search on `name.raw`.

Comment: Yeah i got that ..but the term is used if my field is not_analysed but in this case my field is analysed..

Comment: Thanks..is there any option rather than changing the mapping because i want to do that without reindexing.

Comment: No, you can't do an exact search on an analyzed mapping

Comment: That's what i want to find out..Thnks